# Next.js, getStaticProps not working. TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I created a project starting from create-next-app.
Inside the **Blog.js** page I tried to fetch from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts using the `getStaticProps()` function.

I used the guide https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props#using-getstaticprops-to-fetch-data-from-a-cms. Once everything is implemented, I open the page in the browser and it tells me

```
Server Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
```

**Here is the code**

```
function Blog({ posts }) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {posts.map((post) => (
        <li>{post.title}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
  const posts = await res.json()

  return {
    props: {
      posts,
    },
  }
}

export default Blog
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing the function inside of the component you want to render. The only situation you are going to do this is when you are making dynamic URLs based on some parameter, in that case you will use getStaticProps and getStaticPages mixed.

Try to do something like this:

1. Write your Blog component in a file (Blog.tsx/jsx):

```
function Blog({ posts }) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {posts.map((post) => (
        <li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}

export default Blog
```

2. Go to the page where you will render this component (it could be an index.tsx/jsx for instance)

```
import type { NextPage } from "next";
import Blog from 'wherever it is'

const Home: NextPage = ({posts}) => {
  return (
    <>
          <Blog posts={posts}/>    
    </>
  );
};

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
  const posts = await res.json()
  
  return {
    props: {
      posts,
    },
  }
}


export default Home;
```

P.S. When you are using map, never forget the key property

Comment: Thanks, Bro!! you save my life.
So, I can't write the function getStaticProps() inside the component I want to render?

Comment: You just can writte this function inside a page. You'll use getStaticProps() in two situations:

1. Fetching data from an external API like you did to use this data on current page;
2. Fetching data to create dynamic routes, check it out here: https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/dynamic-routes

Comment: OP's code was taken from the official example in the docs. How is it supposed not to work?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is you implement the Blog component outside of the Page folder.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).